# TextView.setText and a missing refresh

Tags: android

i am starting a new activity from a helperclass with

```
private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {
@Override
   public void run() {
      try {
         Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, Class.forName(myContext.getPackageName() + nextActivity));
         intent.putExtra("Package", myPackage);
         myContext.startActivity(intent);
      } catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("DownloadHelper", "DownloadHelper launcher error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

and then in the new activity i want to change a textView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_author_main);
   final TextView aboutAuthor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutText);
   Log.d("LibAuthorMain", "before getText(): "+aboutAuthor.getText().toString());
   aboutAuthor.setText("test");
   Log.d("LibAuthorMain", "after getText(): "+aboutAuthor.getText().toString());
}
```

The xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/aboutText"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After running it shows in logcat (New Text is the via xml predefined value):

```
before getText(): New Text
after getText(): test
```

But it still shows the old value on screen. Whats wrong?

[solved]
I found the mistake... Sorry, it was 50 cm before my monitor... :( I left a setContentView in the onCreate of the subclass of the (library) class, where i wanted to change the textView. Shame on me. :( Thanks for your time!

Comment: nothing is wrong. Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: may be you meant to use `append` insted of `setText`!. why do you require a thread to launch a activity?

Comment: @blackbelt: And why doesnt it show the new value on screen? It still shows the old value.

Comment: @Raghunandan: No, i want to replace the old value by the actual value.

Comment: @Glueckstiger your question is not that clear, so what i get from your comment is, that it still shows "New Text" on the screen instead of "test"

Comment: @varun bhardwak: I wrote it in the topic "missing refresh". But i hope it is now clear. Sorry :)

Comment: maybe you have more textview with the same id

Comment: @Glueckstiger can you post your layout xml file

Comment: @blackbelt same id textview in same xml can not exist and if it is of different xml then it would have thrown a nullpointer

Comment: @blackbelt: I set up a new textView with a weird name just to get sure. Nope, same problem...

Comment: @blackbelt i mean to say IDE will give a warning for that but programme will compile and the first id text will be changed, you are right

Comment: @Glueckstiger can you post your layout xml file

Comment: @varunbhardwaj: I added xml above.

Comment: I found the mistake... Sorry, it was 50 cm before my monitor... :( I left a setContentView in the onCreate of the subclass of the (library) class, where i wanted to change the textView. Shame on me. :( Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think while launching the activity the path was not correct that means if you evaluate "myContext.getPackageName() + nextActivity" the class is not resolved.
Have you put a dot after myContext.getPackageName() ? if not than put it because without dot it comes out to be like "com.android.testactivityname" and that is not recognized, so you have to put it like "com.android.test.activityname"

Quick solution for you ->

"myContext.getPackageName() + "." +nextActivity" this should work. Please review the variable nextActivity also with the actual name of Activity in your package.

Please feel free to ask any question.